# How to use reward withdrawing via cardano-cli?

Tags: cardano-cli, rewards

Has anyone played around or stumbled upon tutorial examples on how to use reward withdrawing via cardano-cli? I want to study the commands related with "withdraw" keyword. I have not seen examples illustrating their functionality. The commands/args are the one in the photo below
[image]

Note: Originally posted at IOG discord ask-plutus channel https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/826829805387120690/1049778750625169528

Answer (score 0):

At first, try the following command to query the payment address balance:

```
cardano-cli query utxo \
    --address $(cat payment.addr) \
    --allegra-era \
    --mainnet
```

Then use the command that looks like that (do not forget to calculate transaction fees):

```
cardano-cli transaction build raw \
    --tx-in <YourTxHash>#1
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+0
    --withdrawal $(cat stake.addr)+25000000
    --ttl 12345678
    --fee 72500
    --out-file withdraw_rewards.raw
```